# SYSDATE to find average amount of workdays on a project in Oracle sqldeveloper

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sysdate

I am in Database Fundamentals at ETSU. Our instructor is from Bangladesh, so it is hard to understand his lectures at times. Well SYSDATE usage was one of those days. Then in our lab had this question,

> Display the average duration of work (in number of days) for employees                              grouped by job_id. Assume that nobody has resigned or been fired. Use Oracle date function SYSDATE.

After hours of google and stack overflow searching, and questions unanswered by the professor it still stumped me.

I have tried several (SELECT, FROM, GROUP_BY, HAVING, & ORDER_BY) and have finally come here in search of help.

This is my script:

```
     SELECT job_id, hire_date
     FROM hr.employees
     GROUP BY job_id
     HAVING AVG(SYSDATE) - hire_date;
```

This is my error:
         Error starting at line: 1 in command -
         SELECT job_id, hire_date
         FROM hr.employees
         GROUP BY job_id
         HAVING AVG(SYSDATE) - hire_date;
         Error at Command Line : 4 Column : 31
         Error report -
         SQL Error : ORA-00920: Invalid relational operator
         00920. 00000 - "invalid relational operator"

WHAT am I doing wrong?

Comment: `AVG(SYSDATE) - hire_date` is not a boolean condition - which is what the error message is telling you. Plus: you can't calculate the average of a a single date (if there was such an operation defined, it would simply yield sysdate)

Comment: Ah, see that helps me understand more of what SYSDATE is for. Now, when I am asked on a test or have another Lab asking for it I will be better equipped to answer and get it right. I am glad I asked.

Answer (score 0):

> Display the average duration of work (in number of days) for employees grouped by job_id. Assume that nobody has resigned or been fired. Use Oracle date function SYSDATE.

So assuming no employees have been fired since their hiredate, let's see the below example which finds the average duration of work of employees in each department. Also, this assumes all the days of the week(including weekend).

```
SQL> SELECT deptno,
  2    ROUND(AVG(SYSDATE - hiredate), 2) avg_duration
  3  FROM emp
  4  GROUP BY deptno
  5  /

    DEPTNO AVG_DURATION
---------- ------------
        30     12327.79
        20     12135.45
        10     12218.79

SQL>
```

If you do not want to include the weekends, then you need to filter out those dates which are fall in either weekends or holidays.

Hint, `where to_char(that_date, 'Dy') not in ('Sat', 'Sun')`

But, I think the question is too simple and doesn't need to be made so complicated. So, above solution should suffice.

Comment: So okay, I think I got it. I used the AVG, and even used the ROUND. It was not working in the lab. Let me try that and see what happens.    EDIT:                          It worked! Thank you sooooo much. I have been working on this since 10am. Now to turn it in and see if it what he wanted.